# What to do with wobbling laundry machine?

Tags: dryer, washing-machine, clothes-washer, laundry

I have a laundry machine in a condo and have been using it for almost two years (I use it around 1-2 times a week).

Last week when I was washing a heavy duty, I felt my laundry machine was a little shaky, so I decided to adjust the front legs. But after a few adjustments, not only did I not fix the problem, I also forgot the original positions for the screws.

My question is, how can I make sure that my machine's legs are on a perfect plane, because even a slight gap on one leg can cause the laundry machine to shake very hard.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

[image: I have only adjusted the front legs because the two legs at the back are extremely difficult to reach]

Answer (score 1):

An uneven or unbalanced load of laundry can send a washing machine "walking" across the floor in some situations. For a machine to function correctly it should be situated so the case is level (horizontal plane) and plumb (vertical plane). The easiest way to check this is to use a carpenters level. Set the level on the top and adjust the glides up or down. Hold the level on the side of the case and adjust like-wise.

Answer (score 0):

> Some front-loading washers have self-leveling feet in the back. Check your user's manual to determine if your washer has this feature. If it does, you do not need to manually adjust those legs. Tilt the washer forward so that the back of the machine rises about 6 inches from the floor and then gently lower the washer back into position. The self-leveling legs will automatically adjust.

–*How to Level a Front Loader Washer*, [homeguides.sfgate.com](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/level-front-loader-washer-20503.html)

Afterwards, you may have to adjust the front feet. Some top-loaders are also self-leveling.